# gcc throws: undefined reference to `_getcwd'

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, undefined-reference, getcwd

I'm trying to compile this sourceforge-project in ubuntu 11.10 x64: http://vmb.sourceforge.net/

```
Linux users have to compile the devices from sources.
Either obtained from cvs (see: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vmb/) or as a tgz file.
The sources come with Makefiles. If you have make and gcc, just execute make in the top source directory.
```

So i downloaded the .tar.gz, untared it, and run "make" from the /src dir.
But the output says:

```
/vmb/src/opt/option.c:528: undefined reference to `_getcwd'
```

I think this is something with a wrong or missing library. The original project seems to be from Visual Studio.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into the source code at http://vmb.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vmb/vmb/src/opt/option.c?revision=1.21&view=markup:

```
526 void vmb_get_cwd(void)
527 { if (vmb_cwd!=NULL) return;
528 #ifdef WIN32
529   vmb_cwd = _getcwd(NULL,0);
530 #else
531   vmb_cwd = getcwd(NULL,0);
532 #endif
```

Check your configuration for defined **WIN32**. This should not be enabled/defined for Linux.